# Do any old versions of {fmt} support C++98?

Tags: c++, c++98, fmt

I work with a legacy compiler (C++98) and would like to use {fmt} to format strings into a std::ostream. Is there any version of {fmt} that works with C++98, or has C++11 always been a requirement?

I tried using godbolt, adding -std=c++98 to the compile flags, using the oldest tag in GitHub and got a very specific error:

> error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

Comment: `{fmt}` library does not support C++98.  You could try your hand at porting it.  You'd only need to focus on the parts that you use.

Comment: You may have to settle for tinyfmt:  https://github.com/c42f/tinyformat

Comment: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/1066 <- "For C++98 support use version 4.1"

Comment: It won't work with C++98. The easiest fix is probably to enter the current millennium and upgrade your tools to use a version of C++ that's not ancient (there are *many* benefits to doing so, not just fmt).

Comment: Nope. It needs variadic templates; a core C++11 feature. C++98 is ancient history. Good practice means C++23 or at-least C++20.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help all! Unfortunately, updating compilers is not an option when you work with ancient hardware for which newer compilers don't exist (some old TI DSP). I'll give version 4.1 a try, and if that doesn't work then see what I can do with tinyfmt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[{fmt} 4.1](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/releases/tag/4.1.0) is the last version that supported C++98. Starting from version 5.0 {fmt} requires a subset of C++11, quoting [release notes](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/releases/tag/5.0.0):

> Added a requirement for partial C++11 support, most importantly variadic templates and type traits, and dropped `FMT_VARIADIC_*` emulation macros. Variadic templates are available since GCC 4.4, Clang 2.9 and MSVC 18.0 (2013). For older compilers use {fmt} version 4.x which continues to be maintained and works with C++98 compilers.